# Wait to return until button is pushed

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm working on my first big multi-file Java program. When the program starts, my main file calls another file that creates a GUI, populates it and accepts information. It then is supposed to return an `ArrayList`, which my main file is supposed to use.

The issue is that my GUI method is immediately returning with an empty `ArrayList`,  instead of waiting until after a button has been pushed.

This is currently how my `ActionListener`s work

```
close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    System.exit(0);
  }
});

start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    temp = pullInfo(txtOrder, txtRounds);
  }
});
```

Where temp is the `ArrayList` that I want to return at the end.

This is what I have in my main file:

```
 JFrame launch = new LaunchWindow(); 
 ArrayList<Integer> temp = ((LaunchWindow) launch).createGUI();
 rounds = temp.get(0);
 temp.remove(0);
 order = temp;
 connect();
```

I don't want it to run the `rounds = temp.get(0);` until after that `ArrayList` has been populated. How can I make it wait until a button is pushed?

Comment: GUI commands are generally asynchronous.

Comment: @Powerlord Great. That's not very helpful though. Are you saying there isn't a way to do what I want easily?

Comment: put the code into start button's action lsitener

Comment: This looks like a similar question. Does the top response answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935918/swing-gui-doesnt-wait-for-user-input

Comment: These `rounds = temp.get(0);
 temp.remove(0);
 order = temp;
 connect();`

Comment: @Madhan The only problem is that those lines are in a different file. Meaning I would have to return more variables to my main file. Also, I would run in to the same timing issue, just on a different line of code.

Comment: put the above code in a function[for ex dothis()].pass the main's object to LaunchWindow then call object.dothis() from the action listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mixing the answer @Madhan had with something of my own (I think)

I call the GUI file in my main file:

```
JFrame launch = new LaunchWindow(); 
ArrayList<Integer> temp = ((LaunchWindow) launch).createGUI();
```

and then changed my start.addActionListener method, to just call the next method from there.

```
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    temp = pullInfo(txtOrder, txtRounds);
    int rounds = temp.get(0);
    temp.remove(0);
    ArrayList<Integer> order = temp;
    connect(order, rounds);
  }
});
```